# Syntax issues with Rocket Shuttle DB2 Z/OS

Tags: sql, variables, db2

I'm new to Rocket Shuttle and DB2 SQL, but have used Microsoft SQL a decent amount. I've recently been trying to write a query in Rocket Shuttle that fetches data from a database that has empty string for one of the columns, store all appropriate data in a temporary table, then update the empty string column for each entry based on two other pieces of data in the table. However, I seem to be struggling with the syntax for DB2 Z/OS, and have searched online for near a full day for appropriate solutions, but have found none.

My biggest difficulty seems to be simply creating variables. I've tried both of the following in their own individual query:

```
CREATE VARIABLE asdf INTEGER

DECLARE asdf INTEGER
```

and they both return errors. For the CREATE VARIABLE line, the error is

```
BIC00004. DAL01008. An error occurred while accessing the database. ILLEGAL SYMBOL 
"VARIABLE". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: ALIAS AUXILIARY DATABASE FUNCTION 
GLOBAL INDEX. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.50.152
```

and for the DECLARE line, the error is

```
BIC00004. DAL01008. An error occurred while accessing the database. ILLEGAL USE OF 
KEYWORD INTEGER.  TOKEN TABLE STATEMENT , . SCROLL INSENSITIVE SENSITIVE ASENSITIVE NO 
WAS EXPECTED. SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.50.152
```

I'm certain that it's either something minor with syntax that I'm doing wrong, or some setting in my rocket shuttle that's screwing with the SQL, but I honestly have no idea what, as my google searches have gotten me nowhere. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Global variables, which you create using `CREATE VARIABLE`, are only available in DB2 11 for z/OS. For examples of how to write SQL PL procedural code check the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement reference in the manual: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createproceduresqlnative.htm

Comment: I was trying to create only local variables within my current query.